# add common route to multiple vlan in centos

Tags: centos, vlan, route

I have 2 lan cards in my centos 6, one for internet and another for vlans.

I have configured 4 vlans:

```
ifcfg-eth1.10

DEVICE=eth1.10
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:00:00:00
IPADDR=10.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.252
VLAN=yes
```

same configuration for all vlans, but with different ip addresses.

```
ifcfg-eth1.20
ifcfg-eth1.30
ifcfg-eth1.40
```

i have given the gateway ip in the file

```
route-eth1.10

ADDRESS0=10.0.0.1
GATEWAY0=10.0.0.10
NETMASK0=255.255.255.255
```

same for all vlan routes.

```
route-eth1.20
route-eth1.30
route-eth1.40
```

Now my question is:

I have one outbound proxy (`10.10.10.10`) and I want to add route for this IP for all the vlans. How should I do this?

my gateway also has the same /30 network, sorry for the mistake, and i have four different gateways for each vlan.
and I want to ping my outbound proxy (10.10.10.10) from each vlans. 
I can ping outbound proxy from only one vlan , i want all vlan to ping this ip. I can ping the gateway, but not outbound proxy

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Can you [edit] the question and post your network topology? Your VLANs have a `/30` network, but your gatway has a `/32`... Also, is yor gateway the same for all VLANs? `10.0.0.10` is not reachable from `10.0.0.1/30` as configured.

Comment: my gateway also has the same /30 network, sorry for the mistake, and i have four different gateways for each vlan.
and I want to ping my outbound proxy (10.10.10.10) from each vlans. 
I can ping outbound proxy from only one vlan , i want all vlan to ping this ip. I can ping the gateway, but not outbound proxy

Comment: This question could *really* benefit from a diagram!